# Use htaccess in subdirectory to redirect page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I had an html page in a subdirectory - `http://example.com/subdir/old.html`

I've renamed it to `new.html`, and I'd like everything linking to `old.html` to redirect to `new.html`. However, I'd prefer not to complicate the htaccess in the root. So I made an htaccess file in subdir.

I've tried putting these lines in subdir's htaccess file:

```
Redirect 302 old.html http://example.com/subdir/new.html
Redirect 302 /old.html http://example.com/subdir/new.html
Redirect 302 http://example.com/subdir/old.html http://example.com/subdir/new.html
```

But none of them work (`http://example.com/subdir/old.html` gives a 404). Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the backslash before the old.html.

Comment: Same result. Didn't work :(

Comment: What about RedirectMatch ? RedirectMatch 302 old.html http: //example.com/subdir/new.html

Comment: That did it! Thanks! If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It should be something to do with the pattern matching when it is in sub dir, weird, I always use RewriteRule so I never met this before :) Glad to hear RedirectMatch helps.

Comment: In fact I use RewriteRule in.subdirs: if you are interested - http://smozgur.com/blog/apache/using-htaccess-instead-file_exists-for-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try RedirectMatch instead: (I couldn't get Rdirect worked in subdir either)

```
RedirectMatch 302 old.html http://example.com/subdir/new.html
```

Comment: accidental space after `http:`

Comment: Yep, had to post that way in the comment and copy and paste for the answer :)) Thanks for reminding.